MagicDraw OpenAPI - Cannot find any core Classes
I'm trying to programmatically interact with MagicDraw for the first time, but I am having trouble as I am constantly getting errors. Here is a very simple script I am trying to run:
package com.mycompany.plugin;

import com.nomagic.magicdraw.core.Application;

public class MyPlugin {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Application app = Application.getInstance();
            System.out.println("MSOSA Plugin is running!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

I cannot run this because I am getting the error:

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
com/nomagic/magicdraw/core/Application

Essentially I cannot use any of the Core Classes as they are not found. I am using VSCode with Maven, and I have included the JAR files in a local lib folder, and my pom.xml is pointing to those JAR files in the dependencies section. So I believe I have configured everything correctly. But for some reason I am always getting these errors. Please can someone advise?

I have just seen that MagicDraw recommends using Eclipse. I will try with Eclipse and then report back.
